# React defaultValue is causing the filtering function act different than expected

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, jsx, use-state

I have a list of editable inputs, but when I am filtering out one of the items in a `useState` array, it filters the one clicked on only when I use the `value` property, which is uneditable, instead of the `defaultValue` property, which causes the last item of the array to be removed (not the one clicked on).

Is there a way to remove the right while keeping the input editable?

**Here is a sample Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/MatanCL/25hLyj6a/1

And my code:

```
function App () {
  let [myAray1, setMyArray1] = React.useState(['cat', 'dog', 'fish']);
  let [myAray2, setMyArray2] = React.useState(['cat', 'dog', 'fish']);
  return (
    <div>

        Working, but input is uneditable:

        {myAray1.map(animal => <div>
            <input value={animal}/>
            <button onClick={() => {
                const me = animal;
                setMyArray1(myAray = myAray1.filter(animal => animal !== me));
            }}>
                remove
            </button>
        </div>)}

        <br/>

        Removes the wrong one:

        {myAray2.map(animal => <div>
            <input defaultValue={animal}/>
            <button onClick={() => {
                const me = animal;
                setMyArray2(myAray2 = myAray2.filter(animal => animal !== me));
            }}>
                remove
            </button>
        </div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Thank you all!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `key` to your inputs. Like:

```
{myAray2.map(animal =>
   <div>
     <input defaultValue={animal} key={animal} />
     ...
   </div>)
}
```

The reason for doing this is to tell the keys to React explicitly. Furthermore information please read [the official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` is not editable because setting value property makes it a **Controlled Component**

You need to add an `onChange` event to the input to make it editable.

To make sure you're not deleting the wrong element while using filter, make use of the "**Key**" to filter the correct item.

Removes the wrong one:

```
       {myAray2.map(animal => <div>
            <input value={animal} key={animal} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
            <button onClick={() => {
                const me = animal;
                setMyArray2(myAray = myAray2.filter(animal => animal !== me));
            }}>
                remove
            </button>
            <div />)}
```